# Kendo Grid - Is it possible to display list items in different cells?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-grid

I have a list and I'd like to display the items in one column, in different cells/rows. 
I'd tried to solve it with JS, but the items displayed in one cell (the code below, the **Animals** is a string list from the Controller). Any idea would be helpful.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModels.AnimalViewModel>()
    .Name("animalGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Animals).ClientTemplate("#=printItems(Animals)#");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAnimalData", "Animal"))
    )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
function printItems(Names) {
    var result = "";
    var j = Names.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        result = Names[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I'd like to display 3 different properties (strings) in one column. I use in my viewmodel a string list property for these values.

Comment: If the number of columns you need to pivot on is static and not too big them you probably want to do this in your controller and return a flattened model.

Comment: What do you mean about flattended model?

Comment: Magg- Flatten, pivot the row values of an attribute into columns. Your view model does not have to strictly match your domain. So on your view model you simply add the properties for your 15 columns --> public string Animal1{get;set;} public string Animal2{get;set;}...and then map the data in ReadAnimalData.